Warnings when I use tabula-py
I got these warnings when I use tabula-py.
Apr 24, 2024 10:15:55 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument importPage
WARNING: inherited resources of source document are not imported to destination page
Apr 24, 2024 10:15:55 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument importPage
WARNING: call importedPage.setResources(page.getResources()) to do this

How to solve these warnings?
I tried to re-install the tabule-py and install latest version of Java.

Post most relevant code ,  take a better look at warning logs usually you can get answer ...  It is somethig about call setResources ...
